# @Autowiring Service giving NullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, autowired

I am trying to Autowire My Service Class but It is always giving me Null Pointer Exception. The Table for Entitity Is Creating Successfully.

My AppLication Class

```
import com.pubg.players.client.Main;

@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PlayersApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PlayersApplication.class, args);
        Main main = new Main();
        main.method();
    }

}
```

My Main Class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.pubg.players.entity.Profile;
import com.pubg.players.service.ProfileService;

@Component
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    ProfileService service;

//  @Autowired
//  ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void method() {

        System.out.println("Enter Choice");
        System.out.println(
                "1:Create Player\n2:Get All Players\n3:Get Player With Highest Kills\n4:Modify The Best Players Highest Kills\n5:Delete Player\n6:Exit\n\n");
        System.out.println("Enter Choice:");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;
//      System.out.println(Arrays.asList(applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()));
        do {
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
            case 1: {
                System.out.println("Enter User Name and Highest Kills");
                Profile profile = new Profile(sc.next(), sc.nextInt());
                service.createProfile(profile);
                System.out.println("Profile Created With Details :");
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                service.getAllProfiles().forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                System.out.println(service.getProfileWithHighestKills());
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                System.out.println("Enter User Name To Modify");
                String userName = sc.next();
                Profile profile = service.getProfileByName(userName);
                System.out.println("Enter New Kills");
                int newKills = sc.nextInt();
                profile.setHighestKills(newKills);
                service.modifyProfile(profile);
                System.out.println("Profile Modified \n Proof:-" + service.createProfile(profile));
                break;
            }
            case 5: {
                System.out.println("Enter User Name To Delete");
                String userName = sc.next();
                service.deleteProfile(userName);
                break;
            }

            default: {
                System.out.println("You Had One Job, Shame On You\n\n\n");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            }
            }
        } while (choice != 6);
    }

}
```

My Service Class

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.pubg.players.entity.Profile;
import com.pubg.players.repository.ProfileRepository;
import com.pubg.players.service.ProfileService;

@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements ProfileService {

    @Autowired
    ProfileRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Profile createProfile(Profile profile) {
        return repository.save(profile);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Profile> getAllProfiles() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Profile getProfileByName(String name) {
        return repository.getProfileByUserName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Profile getProfileWithHighestKills() {
        return repository.findAll(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "highestKills")).get(0);

    }

    @Override
    public Profile modifyProfile(Profile profile) {
        return repository.saveAndFlush(profile);
    }

    @Override
    public Profile deleteProfile(String name) {
        repository.delete(repository.getProfileByUserName(name));
        return repository.getProfileByUserName(name);
    }

}
```

My Service Interface

```
public interface ProfileService {

    public Profile createProfile(Profile profile);

    public List<Profile> getAllProfiles();

    public Profile getProfileByName(String name);

    public Profile getProfileWithHighestKills();

    public Profile modifyProfile(Profile profile);

    public Profile deleteProfile(String name);

}
```

I have also tried to Print All beans in Application Context But Autowiring Application Context also Gives Null Pointer Exception.

Here's git hub link to the code
https://github.com/Lucifer-77/Players-Spring-Boot.git

Don't know how to proceed. Any Help Much Appreciated

My StackTrace:-

```
Enter Choice
1:Create Player
2:Get All Players
3:Get Player With Highest Kills
4:Modify The Best Players Highest Kills
5:Delete Player
6:Exit


Enter Choice:
1
Enter User Name and Highest Kills
Harry
15
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.pubg.players.client.Main.method(Main.java:37)
    at com.pubg.players.PlayersApplication.main(PlayersApplication.java:16)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Add @ComponentScan or update @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.pubg.players"). Try these!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are instantiating the class Main:

```java
Main main = new Main();
```

When you use `Spring`, you pass the control over instantiation to the `Spring Container` and you should absolutely not construct a class like this. The dependency injection will only work on beans managed (constructed) by Spring.

That said, if you want to execute a code after the context startup, you should use the Spring context listeners, like this:

```java
@Component
public class SampleContextListener {

    @Autowired
    private Main main;

    @EventListener(classes = { ContextStartedEvent.class })
    public void onStartup() {
        main.method();
    }
}
```

If you want to execute before Spring takes control and starts the get the context up, you can't use Spring DI yet. Anyway, it looks like you don't need any of these two.

Now, if you want an application interacting with the terminal and also use Spring, you should give a look on the `Spring Shell` project:

https://projects.spring.io/spring-shell/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code as per your Comments (you can see in Git). Now as soon as the program is started, Nothing Happens. But Conceptually I've understood and it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: The concept is really important. I just updated the answer to add a recommendation for you.